# archive for required library can not be read

Tags: java, maven

I created my first maven project and I get Java build path problem in it.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/simran/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-web/3.1.1/glassfish-embedded-web-3.1.1.jar' in project 'RestfulMessenger' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   RestfulMessenger        Build path  Build Path Problem
```

This jar is present in the location mentioned, I tried deleteing it from there , cleaning the project and updating the maven but nothing fixed the error.

What seems wrong?

Comment: See if you can open the jar file with a Zip utility, it should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing

```
Maven -> Update Project and make sure you check Force Update of Snapshots/Releases
```

Comment: Try refreshing the project or relaunching Eclipse

Comment: I had similar issues in the past, usually I didn't have the patience to find a fix so I sorted them by adding a new Maven installation to Eclipse. Maybe that can help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the corresponding .jar files from local repository and reissuing the maven command did the trick. It seems the .jar files got corrupted while downloading.